# crie uma trigger para permitir fazer emprestimo de livro somente para alunos que tenham status 'MT'

Tags: sql, postgresql

o professor pediu pra fazer uma trigger no postgresql,só que não conseguir fazer não se alguém puder me ajudar,crie uma trigger para permitir fazer emprestimo de livro somente para alunos que tenham status 'MT',
create function emprestimo_livro() returns trigger 
language plpgsql
as 
$$
begin 
    if(
    insert emprestimolivro

return new;
end;
$$ 
bando de  dados,
create schema provaII
set schema 'provaII';

CREATE TABLE ALUNO (
    CDALUNO INTEGER NOT NULL,
    NOME VARCHAR(40) ,
    NMATRICULA VARCHAR(15) ,
    STATUS CHAR(2) );

insert into Aluno values (1, 'Antonio Bandeiras', '00010-2018','MT'),
                         (2, 'Bill Gates',        '00002-2018','RP'),
                         (3, 'Steve Snick',      '00003-2018','AP'),
                         (4, 'Linus Torvals',     '00404-2018','AM')

CREATE TABLE CURSO (
    CDCURSO INTEGER NOT NULL,
    NOMECURSO VARCHAR(20) ,
    VALOR NUMERIC(7,2));

insert into curso values(10, 'ADS', 800.00),
                        (11, 'Quimica',900.00),
                        (12,  'Agronomia', 1000.00),
                        (13,  'Agroindustria', 1100.00)

CREATE TABLE PROFESSOR (
    CDPROFESSOR INTEGER NOT NULL,
    NOME VARCHAR(40));

insert into professor values (20, 'MAXUEEL SANTOS'),
                             (21, 'ANTOIN LIMA'),
                             (22,  'GEORGINA COTRIM'),
                             (23,  'PAULITA FERREIRA')

CREATE TABLE DISCIPLINA (
    CDDISCIPLINA INTEGER NOT NULL,
    NOMEDISCIPLINA varchar(40),
    CDPROFESSOR INTEGER,
    VALOR NUMERIC(7,2));

insert into DISCIPLINA values(30, 'ALGORITMO',20,500.00),
                             (31, 'BANCO DE DADOS',21, 600.00),
                             (32, 'TABD',21, 600.00)

CREATE TABLE SEMESTRE (
    CDSEMESTRE INTEGER NOT NULL,
    ANO VARCHAR(15));

INSERT INTO SEMESTRE VALUES(50,'2017.1'),
                           (51,'2017.2'),
                           (52,'2018.1'),
                           (53,'2018.2')

CREATE TABLE TURMA (
    CDTURMA INTEGER NOT NULL,
    NOMETURMA VARCHAR(20)) ;

INSERT INTO TURMA VALUES(60,'PROGRAMADORES'),
                        (61,'ANALISTAS')

CREATE TABLE MATRICULA (
    CDMATRICULA INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CDCURSO INTEGER,
    CDALUNO INTEGER,
    CDSEMESTRE INTEGER,
    VALOR NUMERIC(7,2),
    CDTURMA INTEGER);

INSERT INTO matricula values( 100, 10, 1, 50,300.00,60),
                            ( 101, 10, 2, 50,400.00,60),
                            ( 102, 12, 3, 50,500.00,61),
                            ( 103, 13, 4, 50,500.00,61),

```
                        ( 104, 10, 1, 51, 300.00, 60),
                        ( 105, 10, 2, 51, 400.00, 60),
                        ( 106, 12, 3, 51, 500.00, 61),                         
                        ( 107, 13, 4, 51, 500.00, 61),

                        ( 108, 10, 1, 52, 300.00, 60),
                        ( 109, 10, 2, 52, 400.00, 60),
                        ( 110, 12, 3, 53, 500.00, 61),                         
                        ( 111, 13, 4, 53, 500.00, 61)
```

CREATE TABLE MATDISCIPLINA (
    CDMATDISCIPLINA INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CDMATRICULA INTEGER,
    CDDISCIPLINA INTEGER,
    MEDIA NUMERIC(7,2),
    STATUS CHAR(2) ,
    CDPROFESSOR INTEGER,
    VALOR NUMERIC(7,2));

```
insert into matdisciplina(cdmatdisciplina,cdmatricula,cddisciplina, status,valor) 
       values( 1,100,30,'AP', 500.00),
             ( 2,100,31,'AP', 600.00),
             ( 3,100,32,'AP', 600.00),
             ( 4,100,33,'AP', 500.00),

             ( 5,101,30,'RP', 500.00),
             ( 6,101,33,'RP', 350.00),
             ( 7,101,34,'RE', 400.00),

             ( 8,102,30,'MT', 350.00),
             ( 9,102,31,'MT', 300.00),

             (10,103,30,'MT', 660.00),
             (11,103,32,'MT', 760.00)
```

CREATE TABLE NOTA (
    CDNOTA INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CDMATDISCIPLINA INTEGER,
    NOTA NUMERIC(7,2),
    REFERENCIA VARCHAR(20) ,
    STATUS CHAR(2));

Insert into nota values
   (1, 1, 8.00, 'Av I',   'AP'),
   (2, 1, 4.00, 'AV II',  'RP'),
   (3, 1, 3.00, 'AV III', 'RP'),
   (4, 2, 6.00, 'Av I',   'RP'),
   (5, 2, 4.00, 'AV II',  'RP'),
   (7, 3, 4.00, 'Av I',   'RP'),
   (8, 3, 4.00, 'AV II',   'RP'),
   (9, 4, 8.00, 'Av I',   'AP'),
   (10, 4, 4.00, 'AV II', 'RP')

create table livro
(
    CDlivro INTEGER NOT NULL,
    nomelivro varchar(40));

Insert into livro values
   (1, 'TABD'),
   (2, 'SO'),
   (3, 'BD'),
   (4, 'BOLSONARO')

create table emprestimolivro
(
    CDemplivro INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CDMATtricula INTEGER,
    cdlivro integer,
    STATUSemp CHAR(2));

Insert into emprestimolivro values
   (1, 100,1,'EM'),
   (2, 100,2,'DE'),
   (3, 100,3,'EM'),
   (4, 101,4,'DE')